# missing requirement osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)

Tags: java, maven

I want to use HttpClient in my project.

pom.xml

```
............. 
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <_wab>src/main/webapp/</_wab>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            ${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}
                        </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *,!com.google.gson
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Embed-Dependency>gson</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Export-Package>
                            org.apache.http.HttpEntity
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Web-ContextPath>${web.context}</Web-ContextPath>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
..................
```

error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't install feature test/0.0.0:
Could not start bundle mvn:ttt/test/1.0-SNAPSHOT in feature(s) test-1.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle ttt.test [234]: Unable to resolve 234.0: missing requirement [234.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)
```

I thought there are some mistakes in "build", but I don't have no idea to solve that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install HTTP client bundle or put it in your `feature.xml` file if you are making `kar` file

```
bundle:install mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.1
```

Comment: This may be the correct answer but please add more details to further clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this question is related to osgi, and your osgi container is based on Karaf (because you are speaking of 'feature').

It's not related to the build of your bundle : you should also deploy your required runtimes dependencies in your container (karaf) : in the feature test, add a `<bundle>` tag for each bundle you need at runtime (with dependency=true), or add a dependency to a feature which already install these bundles.

Moreover, you shouldn't Export-Package org.apache.http.HttpEntity : it's not a package, but a class, and the package "org.apache.http" is provided by another bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Better advice is use httpclient instead of httpclient-osgi, because httpclient-osgi is a bundle, it means before your bundle start ,you need start httpclient-osgi, it will bring some problem(you also need put httpclient-osgi in features). if your function is just use a http-client, use httpclient is enough.just make dependency in source code is ok~